# exponential martingale inequality

Tags: inequality, stochastic-processes, exponential-function, martingales

I stumbled across a claim I couldn't verify. Let $M_t$ be a continuous local martingale, $M_0=0$ a.s. and $\lambda>0$. Then 
$$
\mathbb{E}\left( \exp \left( \lambda M_t \right) \right) \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left(2\lambda^2 \left<M_t\right>\right)\right)}
.$$

Can anybody point me to a proof of this or a similar result? I looked up some Martingale inequalities like Doobs, Bernstein, etc. but they didn't help me at all. Any advice on how to proof it would be also appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write, for $b>0$,
$$
\Bbb E[\exp(\lambda M_t)]=\Bbb E[\exp(\lambda M_t-b\langle M\rangle_t)\cdot\exp(b\langle M\rangle_t)].
$$
Use Cauchy-Schwarz
$$
\Bbb E[\exp(\lambda M_t)]\le\sqrt{\Bbb E[\exp(2\lambda M_t-2b\langle M\rangle_t)]\cdot\Bbb E[\exp(2b\langle M\rangle_t)]}.
$$
Now make a judicious choice of $b$, namely, $b=\lambda^2$.
This is a judicious choice because $\exp(2\lambda M_t-2\lambda^2\langle M\rangle_t)$ is an exponential martingale, hence a positive supermartingale (with initial value equal to $1$), and so has mean value less than or equal to $1$.